# Expose mongodb using cloudflare zero trust tunnels and connect via pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, cloudflare

Hi I am currently trying to set up a mongo db on my home server and expose it to the internet using cloudflare tunnels.

I have a service up and running and have the following for the connection.
`client = MongoClient('<DATABASE_URL>')`

I get this error...
 `pymongo.errors.InvalidURI: Invalid URI scheme: URI must begin with 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://'`

I am tunneling the default ip that mongo gives you.

**UPDATE** 
I tested connecting to the db and just printing the database to the console. I got this result

`Database(MongoClient(host=['<my_domain>:27107'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'test_db')`

I assume that because it says "connect=true" that means it is connecting to the database now.
I tried to add a collection to the database using an example I got online and this is the error I received...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/mongo.py", line 18, in <module>
    x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 628, in insert_one
    self._insert_one(
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 569, in _insert_one
    self.__database.client._retryable_write(acknowledged, _insert_command, session)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1475, in _retryable_write
    with self._tmp_session(session) as s:
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1757, in _tmp_session
    s = self._ensure_session(session)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1740, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1685, in __start_session
    self._topology._check_implicit_session_support()
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 538, in _check_implicit_session_support
    self._check_session_support()
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 554, in _check_session_support
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 238, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No servers found yet, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 63d172246419f5effc5e32d3, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('<my_domain>', 27107) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>]>
```

For reference this is what my pymongo test file looks like.
**mongo.py**

```
import pymongo

con = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://<my_domain>:27107")
db = con["test_db"]

mycol = db["customers"]
print(mycol)
print(db)
mydict = { "name": "John", "address": "Highway 37" }

x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
```

Comment: What is your DATABASE_URL? Redact the password.

Comment: Its a personal server running mongosh. I want to expose it using a personal domain and connect to it using pymongo.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a standard installation, you need to make sure cloudflare tunnel is exposing port 27017. The ingress rule must be:

```
tcp://localhost:27017
```

To connect, just use:

```
pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://user:psw@host.YourTLD/table")
```

It's a good idea to activate authentication if you're exposing the whole server to the internet. You can do it by setting authentication on the mongodb server, or at the cloudflare zero trust edge following this guide:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/tutorials/mongodb-tunnel/

Comment: Hey I don't have a user at the moment so I am trying to connect without. My ingress rule is correct and my connection command looks like this `client = MongoClient('mongodb://<example.domain.com>')` but it doesn't connect.

Comment: you need a tunnel to connect, and a tunnel needs a TLD. You can get both for free: https://youtu.be/MkvAWc_yDMM

Comment: I have a tunnel and a domain the tunnel is using the `tcp://localhost:27017` but mongo doesnt connect.

Comment: are you able to connect from within the same LAN (not from localhost) to the service?... is mongodb running inside a container on the host?

Comment: I am able to connect via lan using the server's ip address e.g. `pymongo.MongoClient("<local_ip>", 27017)` I am running mongo as a service on my ubuntu server if that helps.

Comment: Hi I have added an update to the original question. I think I am able to connect but I am unable to insert anything to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the case here:

- you have a locally deployed mongodb (not some external VM)
- you've set a **Cloudflare tunnel** in order to expose mongodb over **dns**
- and you are having problems to **connect to mongodb** using that dns

So I've recently been trying to do the same, and I got over it with these steps:

- First off, make sure that your **service type**, in Cloudflare Zero Trust, is **TCP**
- URL is probably localhost, make sure you specified port
- download **cloudflared**: [Apple Silicon](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cloudflared) & [everything else probably](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared)
- run this on **your local machine that you want to connect from**:  `cloudflared access tcp --hostname <hostname you've set on Cloudflare ZT> --url <url you want to be forwarded to>`. For example: `cloudflared access tcp --hostname mongo.example.com --url localhost:3000`

Then try to connect with your app to the localhost:3000.

How does this work?

- Well, first you install cloudflared service, which forwards encrypted connection from an app on your machine to the outer internet.
- You can protect access to that forwarded service/app using access rules. I also recommend protecting your app/service, you can do it from MongoDB or Cloudflare ZT, or both.
- Then, you run cloudflared app on your target machine
- connect to Cloudflare servers which forwards your MongoDB instance connection to the specified port on your local machine
- you can access it as its local deployment

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation I will give this a try soon!